# R "complete.cases" Works on one not on the other?

Tags: r

I'm trying to use complete.cases to clear out the NAs from a file.

I've been using help from this site but it isn't working and I'm no longer sure if what I'm trying to do is possible.

```
juulDataRaw <- read.csv(url("http://blah"));
juulDataRaw[complete.cases(juulDataRaw),]
```

I tried this (one of the examples from here)

```
dog<-structure(list(Sample = 1:6
,gene = c("ENSG00000208234","ENSG00000199674","ENSG00000221622","ENSG00000207604","ENSG00000207431","ENSG00000221312")
,hsap = c(0,0,0,0,0,0)
,mmul = c(NA,2,NA,NA,NA,1)
,mmus = c(NA,2,NA,NA,NA,2)
,rnor = c(NA,2,NA,1,NA,3)
,cfam = c(NA,2,NA,2,NA,2))
,.Names = c("gene", "hsap", "mmul", "mmus", "rnor", "cfam"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
dog[complete.cases(dog),]
```

and that works.

- So can mine be done?
- What is the difference between the two?
- Aren't they both just data frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quotes around the numeric values so they are read in as factors. That makes the "NA" just another string rather than an R NA.

```
> juulDataRaw[] <- lapply(juulDataRaw, as.character)
> juulDataRaw[] <- lapply(juulDataRaw, as.numeric)
Warning messages:
1: In lapply(juulDataRaw, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In lapply(juulDataRaw, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In lapply(juulDataRaw, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion
> juulDataRaw[complete.cases(juulDataRaw),]
       age height igf1 weight
55    6.00  111.6   98   19.1
57    6.08  116.7  242   21.7
61    6.26  120.3  196   24.7
66    6.40  115.5  179   19.6
69    6.42  115.6  126   20.6
71    6.43  116.1  142   20.2
80    6.61  130.3  236   28.0
81    6.63  122.2  148   21.6
83    6.70  126.2  174   26.1
84    6.72  125.6  136   22.6
85    6.72  121.0  164   24.4
snipped remaining output.....
```